# Is google custom search api gets results as similar to google assistant?

Tags: google-custom-search, google-search-api

I have question regarding Google Custom Search API, is that works similar such as providing  results as results provided from Google Assistant ?

our requirement is get result for user query and result should be content rather than web URL's/ links which Google Custom Search API is resulting.

Can you please suggest whether Google Custom Search API will work in getting results such as getting results from Google assistant ?

we have seen  "**This API brings to you the same Machine Learning technology that both powers Google’s ability to find specific answers to user questions in Google search and is the language understanding system behind the Google Assistant.**"

Do we get any code samples / API to utilize above system build which is used by the Google Assistant ?

Comment: Can anyone please respond for above question !!

Comment: It seems that you have multiple questions here which are too broad to answer or off-topic on SO. Try defining "similar" first.